# Enable textbox functionality not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik MVC Grid in which I have some columns.
In first column, I have a checkbox and Last column is a Textbox.
I want to enable/disable a textbox on click of checkbox which I have previously set to disabled.

For this,I did this in my js:

```
function enableTextBox() {
    $('[name="Checkbox1"]:checked').change(function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            row.find('#Salary').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            row.find('#Salary').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

My problem is that:
In firefox, this functionality is working fine. i.e. on single click of checkbox , my textbox is enabling.

but in IE9, I need to click twice to enable the textbox.

What should I do for this?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: have you tried removing your pseudo selector ":checked" from your jquery selector?  it looks like you're binding to only checked checkboxes while saying you want to bind to checkboxes in general.

Comment: I want the result on checking and unchecking of checkbox hence i never tried to remove pseudo selector

Answer (score 0):

remove the :checked pseudo class and switch your 'attr' to 'prop'.  here's a simplified example of what you're trying to do:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="textbox" disabled="disabled">
<br />
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="textbox" disabled="disabled">
<br />
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="textbox" disabled="disabled">
<br />
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="textbox" disabled="disabled">
<br />
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="textbox" disabled="disabled">
<br />
```

jquery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        checkbox.next().prop('disabled', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
    });
```

essentially what this does is bind a change event to all checkboxes and set the next element's (in my case a textbox) disabled state to the checkboxes checked state.

your code could be updated like so:

```
function enableTextBox() {
    $('[name="Checkbox1"]').change(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        var row = checkbox.closest('tr');
        row.find('#Salary').prop('disabled', !checkbox.is(':checked'));

    });
    return true;
}
```

you'd ofcourse have to call the enableTextBox function from somewhere to trigger this but this should work.

try out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaZM2/) and let me know if it's what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you, for the answer Josh. But here also the same problem occuring. This code is working correctly for other browsers like Firefox and chrome. But not for IE9. It is enabling the textbox but not on single click,i need to click for 2-3 times to enable it

Comment: when you hit F12 in IE9, what is the browser mode and doc mode? also, what's the environment you're testing this in? (i'm asking because there's the possibility that between the time you click and the time the textbox enables).  i tried the jsfiddle in IE9 with browser mode in IE9 and doc mode in IE9 Standards and it's single click enable/disable.  i'm not sure exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: When I used hit F12 in IE9, my browser mode is:IE9 and Document Mode is: IE9 Standards

Comment: then at that point i'd put a console.log command in the event to see if the event is even being triggered when you click.  it could just be something quirky with your IE, have you tried this with another client machine?